# Force SSL, WWW and remove index.php htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

How can I achieve all of this using htaccess. Thus far I have -

**To enforce SSL**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

**And To remove index.php**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it seems to work for the most part but when i enter something like - "example.com/index.php", i get an error. It is redirected to

```
https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/
```

I know why its happening but can't figure out a rule to combine everything I need and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to take a guess, you're missing the `L` flag in the first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Without the L flag, the request gets marked as "redirect" but continues on to have the other rules processed. And by the result you're seeing, it looks like the 2 rules are interferring with each other.

---

> But is there any way to reduce the redirects when I type example.com/index.php

Not sure if this will work, because I can't test it, but maybe something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(index\.php)?$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi @jon. Thanks for the help. You are right. But is there any way to reduce the redirects when I type example.com/index.php. Right now it will do two redirects first to htts://www.example.com/index.php and then to htts://www.example.com/